# jquery resizable not working properly

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

I am quite new in javascript/jquery. I am making resizable divs using jquery-ui-resizable. Here I have created the fiddle but can't figure out why jquery ui resizable is not working.

```
    <div class="container">
  <div class="left-container">
  </div>
  <div class="right-container">
    <div class="child first">
    </div>
    <div class="child second">
    </div>
   </div>
</div>

$(".child").resizable({
   //"handles": "w, e"
})
```

Any help would be appreciated.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aoaLqngj/)

Comment: Kenny, I am trying to understand what you're doing.  Your JSFiddle is more clear though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add a jquery-ui theme in order for this to work.

Try this line of code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

Comment: I faced the same problem yesterday when trying to use accordion.

Comment: Yes, he is correct.  You should do this with JSFiddle on the left side where it says external resources.  add https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css and click the + sign.

Answer (score 2):

on the following link:

first clear the html and replace it with:
`<div></div>`

then in the style sheet replace it with:

```
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 5px;
width: 50px;
height: 150px;
margin: 10px;
```

and finally script code:
`$("div").resizable()`

almost done...